# Every 10 mango remove 1 mango

Tags: javascript, math

I want to know if someone have the formula to count every 10. Because I already have the formula to remove 1 it's :

```
var mango = 20
var a = mango / 10
var result = mango - a
```

But if `mango = 6` il still calculating.

Comment: result = mango - ~~(mango/10);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only the [integer part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) of the calculation, because the rule says every 10 just one.

```js
var mango = 25,
    a = Math.floor(mango / 10), // get only the integer part of calculation
    result = mango - a;

console.log(result);
```

> every 1 month remove 2.5% of the price to the price

```js
var price = 100,
    days = 100,
    month = Math.floor(days / 30),
    result = price - price * (2.5 * month) / 100;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! And a just a quick question for 1 remove 2.5% is that possible ?

Comment: can you give an example for that?

Comment: every 1 month remove 2.5% of the price to the price